# GroupBy method syntax for subquery

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query syntax query that I need to convert into a method syntax because I need to add the .Take() operator at the end of a subquery. This is what I have:

```
var TheQuery = (from col in MyDC.SomeTable
                ordery ....
                where.....
                group s by s.SomeColumnID into TheGroups
                from subgroup in TheGroups
                ....)
```

I'm having trouble converting that into method syntax; this is what I want to write:

```
var TheQuery = MyDC.SomeTable
                .OrderByDescending(....
                .Where(.....
                .GroupBy(s => s.SomeColumnID into TheGroups) //here
                .TheGroups //here
                .Where(....
```

I'm sure it's easy but I can't figure it out. How do I convert my query into method syntax so that the grouping can be the used for a subquery?

### Edit after Shyju's attempt

This is what I now have:

```
var TheQuery = MyDC.SomeTable
                     .OrderByDescending(s => s.ExpirationDate)
                     .Where(s => s.ExpirationDate < DateTime.UtcNow)
                     .Where(s => s.UserID == SomeParameter)
                     .GroupBy(s => s.BasketID, v => v, (k, v) => new SomeModel() 
                      {
                           BasketID = v.BasketID,
                           ExpirationDate = v.ExpirationDate,
                           SomeProp = v.SomeProp
                           ....
                      }).Take(1).ToList();
```

I'm grouping all the elements by BasketID that have elements with an ExpirationDate that's less than the UtcNow and I only want the most recent element of each basket and those whose SomeProp property (a byte) is equal to 2, 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filters elements in each group doing this:

```
var TheQuery = MyDC.SomeTable
            .OrderByDescending(....
            .Where(.....
            .GroupBy(s => s.SomeColumnID)
            .Select(items => new { Key = items.Key, 
                                   Values = items.Where(i => i.SomeOtherColumnId == someId).Take(10) });
```

If you want to gets only the filtered elements of each group in a single array them use `SelectMany()`:

```
var TheQuery = MyDC.SomeTable
            .OrderByDescending(....
            .Where(.....
            .GroupBy(s => s.SomeColumnID)
            .SelectMany(items => items.Where(i => i.SomeOtherColumnId == someId).Take(10));
```

**EDIT**:

If you need only the first/top element of each group that meets a condition:

```
var TheQuery = MyDC.SomeTable
            .Where(s => s.ExpirationDate < DateTime.UtcNow)
            .Where(s => s.UserID == SomeParameter)                     
            .Select(v => new SomeModel
            {
                BasketID = v.BasketID,
                ExpirationDate = v.ExpirationDate,
                SomeProp = v.SomeProp
                //....
            })
            .GroupBy(s => s.BasketID)
            .Select(items => items.Where(item => item.SomeProp == 2 ||
                                                 item.SomeProp == 3 ||
                                                 item.SomeProp == 4).OrderByDescending(item => item.ExpirationDate).First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for grouping the data, this should work.

```
var grouped2 = MyDC.SomeTable
             .GroupBy(s => s.Name, v => v, (k, v) => new {k, v});
```

You can definitely call the `Take` method when you group the results.

```
var groupedWithFiveItemsPerGroup = MyDC.SomeTable.GroupBy(s => s.Name, v => v, 
                               (k, v) => new {  Name = k, FiveItems= v.Take(5) });
```

If you want to add a where clause on your grouped data, you can do that as well.

```
var groupedWithFiveItemsPerGroup = MyDC.SomeTable.GroupBy(s => s.Name, v => v, 
         (k, v) => new {  Name = k, FiveItems= v.Where(r=>r.SomeProperty=="Hi").Take(5) });
```

*Replace `s.Name` with your property name.*

Comment: In my query syntax, I have a subquery that uses the results of the grouping; how do I do the same in method syntax?? I need a where clause on the groups and that's what I'm struggling with.

Comment: So you want to add a where clause to your grouped result ? Why not simply add a where clause to the end of the line expression ?

Comment: Well from the subgroups I need to take the list of the first ones that matches a where clause.

Comment: Then add the where clause before .Take(5)

Comment: Can you show me in code? That's EXACTLY what I'm stuck on.

Comment: Ok, but I don't need the top 5 elements, I need the list of the top elements of each group that meet a where clause. So there could be many groups and out of each group I need the first element where some condition is met and then end the query with a .ToList()

Comment: You need the first element? Change `Take(5)` to `Take(1)` ?

Comment: I think `FirstOrDefault()`, but then you (@frenchie) need to indicate which sort order defines "first".